# How to import cordova.js in Salesforce Visualforce ios hybrid app?

Tags: ios, cordova, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

In Salesforce [examples](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) of hybrid app in `VFConnector` project there is `shared-www` folder which contain only `bootconfig.json` file, instead of `index.html` and other JS-files, as in other examples.

The difference is in `"startPage": "/apex/BasicVFPage"`, instead of `"index.html"`.

The question is: how can we use cordova plugins with such structure of project? For example, when we load `index.html`, we use

> `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

But when all the content becomes from server, how to import `cordova.js` here?

Comment: have you read this? http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/09/new-salesforce-mobile-sdk-2-3-with-cordova-3-5-support/

Comment: Yes. In other examples it works fine, but in Visualforce`s project (VFConnector) - not

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: http://michaelwelburn.com/2015/05/04/tips-tricks-for-hybrid-remote-mobile-apps-using-salesforce-mobile-sdk-cordova/

It works for me!